# Use a specific Python interpreter to run a specific module

Tags: python, windows, shebang

I have created a dedicated Python interpreter in Windows called `nPython.exe`. It is a Python 2.7 interpreter, using Python.NET sources of `pythonnet-develop`.

I have a specific module. I want this module to always be executed by `nPython.exe`. The module is executed in many different ways: double clicking the module, or using Visual studio, or as part of existing scripts.

I thought using a shebang line at the beginning of the file (i.e. `#!C:\dir\nPython.exe`) might work, but unfortunately I had no success.

Note, I don’t want to overwrite the `python.exe` all users have as part of the standard Python installation.

Comment: Shebangs with paths aren't used in Windows

Comment: Install Python 3 to get the [py launcher](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#python-launcher-for-windows). Then you can use a shebang, exactly like you want. Or just define a new filetype and association, e.g. `ftype nPython.File="C:\dir\nPython.exe" "%1" %*` and `assoc .npy=nPython.File`. Then just use the .npy filename extension for nPython scripts.